# Padding on background image hover creating extra unwanted space

Tags: html, css, background-image, padding

so I have a simple problem. I have a hover background image change effect, however there seems to be some extra padding on hover that I can't get rid off.

**My jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/G9dFa/

I've tried adjusting the padding of the background image on my hover, however adding the needed 20 pixels also adds extra spacing. Going to 0 does not allow the background image fill the space :(

[image]

Any tips appreciated! :)

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINK 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">OUR BLOG</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="search">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
  width: 994px;
  height: 27px;
  background-image:url('http://leongaban.com/_stack/background_padding/assets/images/bg_nav.gif');
}

#nav ul li {
  height: 27px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 20px 6px 20px;
  line-height:30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  display: inline;
}

#nav ul li a {
  padding: 8px 0px 6px 0px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 8px 20px 6px 20px;
  background-image:url('http://leongaban.com/_stack/background_padding/assets/images/bg_nav_hover.gif');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go. Changed some css. 
You had padding on the li when it should've been on the anchor. 
Changed your li's to float left instead of display:inline; 
Made background-image to background and added a x-axis repeat.

http://jsfiddle.net/G9dFa/6/

```
    .nav {
  width: 994px;
  height: 27px;
  background-image:url('http://leongaban.com/_stack/background_padding/assets/images/bg_nav.gif');
}

#nav ul li {
  height: 27px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height:30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  float:left;
}

#nav ul li a {
  padding: 8px 20px 6px 20px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*-webkit-background-size:100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size:100% 100%;
  background-size:100% 100%;*/
  background:url('http://leongaban.com/_stack/background_padding/assets/images/bg_nav_hover.gif') repeat-x;
}​
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

http://jsfiddle.net/r9dTG/

EDIT:

Wow we all came up with similar results, the only thing I would stress is that with a declared line height on the LI tag padding top and padding bottom on the anchor tag does not make much sense. I would use one or the other not both since the math was not adding up anyhow, less to calculate and maintain.

Comment: I agree! Good catch! And hello to a fellow Metro-chicagoian!

Answer (score 1):

Put all the styling on the `A`-tag. Get rid of everything on the `LI` except `display:inline`. Add `display:block` to your `A`-tag.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you anchors does not take the full space because you set a padding to the LI elements:

- remove the padding from the LI
- add the padding to the anchor tag

---

```
#nav ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 8px 20px 6px 20px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
  background-image:url('http://leongaban.com/_stack/background_padding/assets/images/bg_nav_hover.gif');
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/W2bL2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Diodeus:

Put all the styles onto your anchor tag `a`.

Change your anchor tag style to be `display: inline-block`.

Display inline-block elements have a funny bug in some browsers where if there's ANY white-space between items, it will render a funky space. To fix this, you need to fix your HTML to put the `li` items end to end. i.e. actually REMOVE the spaces between them.

Here's an example with your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/G9dFa/

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the padding on the `<li>`, try removing that and it should work